# MVC 3 - Display Dialog Popup in ActionResult

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5

Let me start by saying I'm very new to MVC; I have inherited an application at my company and am making changes to an edit function.  In this scenario, we are checking for an existing record in the database before allowing the user to edit the record.  Originally, we displayed an error saying that the item already exists.  The change I am trying to implement is to display a message alerting the user that an item with the same information exists, and then give them the option to overwrite the existing data or cancel out completely, but only if a certain option is selected.

```html
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(EditModel details)
        {
            var editItem = new Object();

            var existingItem = db.GetItem(User.ID, editItem.Number);
            if (existingItem != null)
            {
                if (existingItem.Option == 0)
                {
                    // Display confirmation and then continue with edit if yes, if no then cancel
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error");
                    return View(details);
                }
            }

            //Continue operation
        }
```

Is there a way to go about implementing jQuery or some sort of javascript call to achieve this?  Or is there a better way to do this?  I'm open to suggestions, and can provide any necessary information needed to clarify what I'm trying to accomplish.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are lots of ways you could do this. JavaScript is just one option. Another option would be to return a different view with a button to "overwrite" which posts to an "overwrite" action. This is quite a broad question as it stands.

Comment: @AntP I figured it would be a broad question.  I'm sure there are many possible ways to do this.  I was just looking for suggestions or samples on what I could do because, at this time, I'm not even sure where to go, or what would be an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would return some json such as "Exists" in your line where you have your comment "// Display confirmation and then continue with edit if yes"

```
return Json("Exists");
```

Then in your post request I would check that response and use a dialog if it exists

```
$.post(url,{id:$id}, 
function(data){
     if(data == "Exists")
          showDialog();
});
```

Thats how i would handle it.